# Specfial character and control M character needs to be removed from file and convert it to column level data file

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, linux-mint

Sample file:

```
##----unwanted data/header/trailer-----
---spaces---
##----unwanted data/header/trailer-----
-----spaces----
^A123124134325234 ^MâNAME Xã LAURA ^MâLASTNAME Xã TRAN ^MâAGE Xã 21 ^MâADDRESS Xã 123 street ^MâPLACE Xã QWE ^MâSUBJECT Xã MATHS ^MâDOB Xã 11-10-1990 ^MâDOJ Xã 01-06-2011 ^MâCOUNTRY Xã IND ^MâROLLNO Xã 1001 ^MâPINCODE Xã 11121312 ^MâSUPERVISOR Xã ABC
^A123ASDAAAA1234123 ^MâNAME Xã JOE ^MâLASTNAME Xã MARTIN ^MâAGE Xã 25 ^MâADDRESS Xã XYZ street ^MâPLACE Xã MNO ^MâSUBJECT Xã HISTORY ^MâDOB Xã 01-10-1991 ^MâDOJ Xã 12-06-2010 ^MâCOUNTRY Xã US ^MâROLLNO Xã 1002 ^MâPINCODE Xã 1000312 ^MâSUPERVISOR Xã RTY
^AADBBB112HBS67HB ^MâNAME Xã NARESH ^MâLASTNAME Xã SAINI ^MâAGE Xã 27 ^MâADDRESS Xã 67 PLOT 43 HOUSE NO ^MâPLACE Xã TPPO ^MâSUBJECT Xã CHEMISTRY ^MâDOB Xã 11-08-1992 ^MâDOJ Xã 07-10-2012 ^MâCOUNTRY Xã IND ^MâPINCODE Xã 132113^MâSUPERVISOR Xã BPO
----spaces----
##----unwanted data/header/trailer---
----spaces-----
##----unwanted data/header/trailer---
-----spaces-----
```

I want to remove `^Mâ` and `Xã` from each record line and convert it to column level data file:

```
NAME;LASTNAME;AGE;ADDRESS;PLACE;SUBJECT;DOB;DOJ;COUNTRY;ROLLNO;PINCODE
LAURA;TRAN;21;123 street;QWE;MATHS;01-10-1991;01-06-2011;IND;1001;11121312
JOE;MARTIN;25;XYZ street;MNO;HISTORY;01-10-1991;12-06-2010;US;1002;1000312
NARESH;SAINI;27;67 PLOT 43 HOUSE NO;TPPO;CHEMISTRY;11-08-1992;07-11-2012;IND;;132113
```

I am not sure how to start working on this type of file. It would be great if anyone can help me out on this one.

I am able to remove spaces from the file, that's the only thing I have achieved. Below is the code I have tried to remove spaces.

```
awk '{ $1=$1 };1' FILE_NAME
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E '/^[#-]/d; s/^\^[^ ]+ //; s/\^Mâ([^ ]+) +Xã *([^ ^]+)/\1\t/g; s/\t$//' < FILE_NAME | head -n1
sed -E '/^[#-]/d; s/^\^[^ ]+ //; s/\^Mâ([^ ]+) +Xã *([^ ^]+)/\2\t/g; s/\t$//' < FILE_NAME
```

Line #1 outputs the column names with a tab character in between each column name.
Line #2 outputs the data for each column with a tab character in between each column.

HTH